# Последовательное выполнение JSONP

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsonp

Мне нужно выполнить некое количество запросов получить ответ и если все выполнилось без ошибок, то отправить еще некое количество запросов внутри исходя из пришедших данных.
Как можно сделать выполнение последовательно. Чтобы не происходила новая итерация, пока не закончилась предыдущая.

```
for (var i in items) {
    $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        url: 'https://example.com/method?callback=?',
        data: items[i],
        success: function(result) {
            if(result.response) {
              //нужно выполнить еще jsonp запрос исходя из пришедших данных
            }
        }
    });
}
```

upd: 
В качестве решения выбрал такой вариант.

```
var q = items.reduce(function (prev, item) {
    return prev.then(function () {
        return $.ajax({
            dataType: 'json',
            url: 'https://example.com/method/methodOne?callback=?'
        }).then(function (results_one) {
            console.log(results_one);
            return $.ajax({
                dataType: 'json',
                url: 'https://example.com/method/methodTwo?callback=?'
            }).then(function (results_two) {   
                console.log(results_two);
            });
        });
    });
}, $.when([]));
```

Comment: Есть  в `jquery` штучка  с названием     `$.when()`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, я пробовал, но я не понял как с ней работать в моей ситуации

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### 1.

Два запроса подряд делаются так:

```
var q = $.ajax(...)
  .then(function(firstResults) {
    return $.ajax(...)
  })
```

При этом в `q` попадет обещание (promise) результатов второго запроса. Обратите внимание на `return`  - возврат результата выполнения `$.ajax` из метода `then` продолжает цепочку. Без него `q` будет обещанием первого запроса, а не второго. Если надо собрать данные из двух запросов подряд - делаем так:

```
var q = $.ajax(...)
  .then(function(firstResults) {
    return $.ajax(...)
      .then(function(secondResults) {
        return { first: firstResults, second: secondResults } // Или любой другой способ комбинирования результатов
      })
  })
  .then(function(results) {
    ... // Обрабатываем результаты 2х последовательных запросов
  })
```

### 2.

Если нужна цепочка длиннее - лучше ее наращивать не "внутри", а "снаружи" - это позволит избежать неконтролируемого роста вложенности:

```
var q = $.ajax(...)
  .then(function(firstResults) {
    return $.ajax(...)
      .then(function(secondResults) {
        return { first: firstResults, second: secondResults } // Или любой другой способ комбинирования результатов
      })
  })
  .then(function(results) {
    return $.ajax(...)
      .then(function(thirdResults) {
        results.third = thirdResults
        return results // Или любой другой способ комбинирования результатов
      })
  })
  .then(function(results) {
    ... // Обрабатываем результаты 3х последовательных запросов
  })
```

### 3.

Если нужно несколько запросов сделать параллельно - на помощь приходит `$.when`:

```
var q1 = $.ajax(...)
var q2 = $.ajax(...)
var q = $.when(q1, q2)
  .then(function (result1, result2) {
    ... // Обработка результатов 2х параллельных запросов
  })
```

Разумеется, каждый из `q1` и `q2` может быть не одним запросом, а цепочкой запросов.

### 4.

Если нужен параллельный цикл по объектам с отправкой запроса на каждый - это делается так:

```
var qs = items.map(function (item) {
    return $.ajax(...) // тут может быть и цепочка запросов
})
var q = $.when.apply($, qs).then(function() { return [].concat(arguments) })
  .then(function (results) {
    ... // Здесь results - массив ответов
  })
```

### 5.

Последовательный цикл по объектам из массива реализуется сложнее, но колдунство тут не очень сильное:

```
var q = items.reduce(function (prev, item) {
  return prev
    .then(function (results) { 
       return $.ajax(...)
        .then(function (result) {
          results.push(result)
          return results
        })
    })
}, $.when([]))
```

---

Общее свойство всех комбинаций выше - если хоть один запрос падает, то вся цепочка падает, и дальнейшие запросы прекращаются. Обработать эту ошибку можно также, как и для любого запроса ajax (но для jsonp ошибки, кажется, нормально не обрабатываются):

```
q.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  console && console.error(textStatus)
})
```

Но вот возобновить обработку цепочки после ошибки - в jquery уже не так-то и просто. Если вам такое понадобится - лучше перейти на [es6 Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), которые можно заполучить для любого браузера [множеством](https://github.com/jakearchibald/es6-promise) [разных](https://github.com/lahmatiy/es6-promise-polyfill) [способов](https://github.com/getify/native-promise-only).

Из отличий jquery promise от es6 Promise - Promise.all принимает массив, а не список аргументов, это чуть усложняет пункт 3 - но значительно упрощает пункт 4.
Также надо не забывать, что jquery promise можно превратить в es6 promise через вызов `Promise.resolve(q)` - а обратно оно превращается через `$.when(p)`.

Comment: Огромное спасибо. Сейчас пробую и вроде должно полностью решить всю проблему. А можете еще подсказать как к примеру ограничить количество запросов в секунду? При этом же подходе.

Comment: Я обновил вопрос, добавив вариант который мне больше всего подходит. Вот исходя из него как мне ограничить количество запросов?

Comment: @geekartemiy это уже другой вопрос, и не менее крупный. Задайте его отдельно.

Comment: Хорошо. [Вот.](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/470697/Ограничение-количества-запросов-в-секунду?noredirect=1#comment526394_470697)

Answer (score 0):

Там в коментах предлагали использовать `$.when`, я к сожалению с JQuery не знаком и могу предложить только топорное решение :)

```
function getItems(items)
 {
  var needRes=1; // Счетчик ожидаемых результатов
  var newItems=[]; // Массив элементов для следующей серии запросов

  function resultArrieved()
   {
    needRes--;
    if(!needRes) getItems(newItems); // Если это последний ответ - запускаем следующий цикл запросов
   }
  for (var i in items) {
   needRes++;
   $.ajax({
         dataType: 'json',
         url: 'https://example.com/method?callback=?',
         data: items[i],
         success: function(result) {
           if(result.response) {
          // тут из ответа извлекаем данные для вторых вызовов, запускаем их ...
            $.ajax(
                   success: function(result) { .... resultArrieved(); }
                  )
          // Если вызывать второй запрос не надо, то сразу тут вызываем resultArrieved();
         }
        }
   });
  }
  needRes--; // Все запросы отосланы, можно запускаться второй раз, когда придет последний ответ
 }
```

Вводится счетчик отосланных запросов `needRes`, изначально выставляется в 1, что бы при преждевременном приходе ответа (хотя мне кажется это маловероятным) он не стал равен 0 и это не вызвало следующую серию запросов. Когда все запросы отосланы, он уменьшается на 1 и тем самым при приходе последнего ответа он сможет стать равным нулю.

В данном варианте, если не будет хотя бы одного success ничего более не произойдет. Если надо выполнять какие либо специальные действия при ошибках или игнорировать ошибки и несмотря на них порождать следующую серию вызовов - то надо сделать для ajax обработчик `error` в котором так же уменьшать `needRes` и выполнять какие то действия если он 0

А вообще мне кажется, что такая архитектура излишне нагружает сервер пачками запросов и возможно стоит рассмотреть вариант с передачей на сервер одного запроса в ответ на который он пришлет одним ответом все данные, сам собрав их рекурсивно.

Comment: к сожалению у меня нет возможности контролировать ответ от сервера настолько сильно, чтобы он мне за 1 раз все вернул, я выполняю запросы к стороннему api. Я попробую ваш вариант, но мне кажется вы меня не совсем правильно поняли. Мне не нужно выполнять этот же запрос при завершении ajax, мне нужно за 1 итерацию сделать запрос и исходя из пришедших данных совершить совершенно другой ajax запрос, дождаться и его выполнения и только после этого запускать следующую итерацию.

Comment: Тогда там где мой комментарий стоит, вы запускаете свой второй запрос. needRes не уменьшаете, а уменьшите его только когда когда вернется ответ от второго запроса. И тогда на общее завершение работы так же проверите в обработчике этого второго запроса.

Comment: В ответ добавил функцию resultArrieved() для удобства из нескольких мест вызывать событие завершения отдельной ветви подзапросов