# Ограничение количества запросов в секунду

Tags: javascript, ajax, requests

Каким образом можно будет ограничить количество запросов в секунду?
Есть некий скрипт:

```
var q = items.reduce(function (prev, item) {
    return prev.then(function () {
        return $.ajax({
            dataType: 'json',
            url: 'https://example.com/method/methodOne?callback=?'
        }).then(function (results_one) {
            console.log(results_one);
            return $.ajax({
                dataType: 'json',
                url: 'https://example.com/method/methodTwo?callback=?'
            }).then(function (results_two) {   
                console.log(results_two);
            });
        });
    });
}, $.when([]));
```

Необходимо, чтобы количество запросов не превышало N (в противном случае сервер выдает ошибку).

Comment: Это делается на стороне сервера, а не в js.

Comment: @Visman, и даже когда я работаю с api стороннего ресурса?

Comment: Вас беспокоит череда промисов с запросами?

Comment: @AleksanderK., не совсем понял. Меня беспокоит что у меня может быть очень много запросов к серверу, но мне можно делать только около 20 в секунду и при превышении этого лимита, сервер ругается.

Comment: @geekartemiy, можете например слать запрос с задержкой 3 секунды

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Считайте запускаемые запросы. Например перед `$.ajax()` поставьте `requestCount += 1`. При этом `requestCount` должен быть виден из всех запросов;
2. Перед каждым запросом проверяйте не превысил-ли счетчик заданный порог. Если превысил - делаем паузу в 1 секунду и после паузы сбрасываем счетчик.

Паузу можно сделать примерно так:

```
function sleep(duration) {
    var defer = $.Deferred();
    setTimeout(function() {
        defer.resolve();
    }, duration);
    return defer.promise();
}
```

Результат выполнения `sleep()` нужно возвращать после внутри функции `.then()`

Comment: Не пойму, вы говорите что нужно выполнять функцию sleep() перед ajax если мы привесили порог и возвращать её нужно в конце then, и еще в конце какого then? их там 3. Я пробую и у меня не получается сделать остановку.

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать что-то вроде этого:

```
function timeoutAjax(conf, timer) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        $.ajax(conf).done(function() {
            setTimeout(resolve, timer * 1000);
        }).reject(reject);
    });
}

timeoutAjax(20).then(function() {
    return timeoutAjax({/* ajax 1 */}, 20);
}).then(function() {
    return timeoutAjax({/* ajax 1 */}, 20);
}).then(function() {
    console.log({/* ajax 1 */}, 3);
});
```