# Можно ли привязаться к событию ajax\getJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

что имею

http://jsfiddle.net/27rafmcq/3/

```
    $(function() {
      var seriesOptions = [],
       // seriesCounter = 0,
        names = [{
          'div': 'con',
          'ids': [{
            'name': 'MSFT'
          }]
        }, {
          'div': 'con2',
          'ids': [{
            'name': 'AAPL'
          }, {
            'name': 'MSFT'
          }]
        }, {
          'div': 'con3',
          'ids': [{
            'name': 'GOOG'
          }]
        }];

      /**
       * Create the chart when all data is loaded
       * @returns {undefined}
       */
      function createChart(div) {

        $('#' + div).highcharts('StockChart', {

          rangeSelector: {
            selected: 4
          },

          yAxis: {
            labels: {
              formatter: function() {
                return (this.value > 0 ? ' + ' : '') + this.value + '%';
              }
            },
            plotLines: [{
              value: 0,
              width: 2,
              color: 'silver'
            }]
          },

          plotOptions: {
            series: {
              compare: 'percent'
            }
          },

          tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b> ({point.change}%)<br/>',
            valueDecimals: 2
          },

          series: seriesOptions
        });
      }

      $.each(names, function(i, name) {
       var seriesCounter = 0;
        for (var x = 0, cnt = Object.keys(name['ids']).length; x < cnt; x++) {
           console.log(x);
          var name_ = name['ids'][x]['name'];
          $.getJSON('https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=' + name['ids'][x]['name'].toLowerCase() + '-c.json&callback=?', function(data) {

            seriesOptions[i] = {
              name: name_,
              data: data
            };

            // As we're loading the data asynchronously, we don't know what order it will arrive. So
            // we keep a counter and create the chart when all the data is loaded.
            seriesCounter += 1;

            if (seriesCounter === cnt) {
              createChart(name['div']);
            }
          });
        }
        seriesCounter = 0;
      });
    });
```

таким образом нет никакой гарантии что данные придут когда нужно. каким образом можно гарантировать что за один цикл я получу массив всех данных, затем его отобразить и рисовать следующий график?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/470474/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-jsonp/470511

Answer (score 0):

Тут нужно использовать технологию [Promise](https://learn.javascript.ru/promise) или, чтобы не возиться с поддержкой браузерами, [jQuery.Deferred](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/).

Нужно создать deferred в который поместить все ajax-апросы выполняемые для одного графика. Когда все запросы будут выполнены вызовется обработчик в котором и нужно будет вызвать createChart.