# Последовательное выполнение ajax запросов

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ситуация обстоит так:
Ajax возвращает массив и после этого для каждого элемента в этом массиве делается ajax запрос, и для одного элемента, внутри одного ajax запроса делается еще один ajax запрос
Постарался изобразить это схематично

```
ajax 1
success{
 foreach array{
    ajax 2
    success {
         ajax 3
         success {
              действие 1
         }
    }
    ajax 4
    success {
         действие 2
    }
    ajax 5
    success {
         действие 3
    }
  }
}
```

Получается так, что действие 1 выполняется в самую последнюю очередь, а нужно, что бы всё выполнялось по-порядку. Как разрешить выполнение 2 и 3 действия только после выполнение первого? При том может быть так, что ajax 2 не будет существовать, и поэтому засовывать 4 и 5 ajax запрос в функцию success ajax 3 не вариант.

Comment: попробуйте установить `async : false`

Comment: функция `ajax` возвращает promise - используйте его.

Comment: добавь пример кода, который уже есть

Comment: @Shadow33 Это плохой вариант: синхронные аякс-запросы в хроме deprecated. Для подобных вещей есть deferred или promise API

Comment: @ilya, просто будешь плодить ветки `.then(function () { $ajax...then(function () { $ajax....then(function) {}})})`

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев, какой-то плохой пример и к тому же не совсем верный

Comment: @Grundy не, я привел привел как это делается в лоб) А на самом деле не понятно зачем такое делает, т.к. это убьет сервер в хлам от такой нагрузки. Задача поставлена не верна и продумана явно не верно

Answer (score 1):

Используйте цепочку обещаний.

Каждый ajax-запрос возвращает обещание (promise). У него можно вызвать метод `then`, чтобы выполнить некоторое действие по окончанию запроса. Фокус в том, что метод `then` тоже возвращает обещание. Вот пример:

```
$.ajax(...).then(function (resp0) {
  // вызов трех запросов:

  var q1 = $.ajax(...).then(function (resp1) {
    var q11 = $.ajax(...);
    return $.when(resp1, q11);
  })
  var q2 = $.ajax(...);
  var a3 = $.ajax(...);

  // Первое действие - по завершению обоих запросов q1
  var a1 = q1.then(function(resp1, resp11) {
    console.log(resp1, resp11);
  });

  // Второе действие - по завершению q2 и первого действия:
  var a2 = $.when(q2, a1).then(function (resp2) {
    console.log(resp2);
  });

  // Третье действие - по завершению q3 и первого действия:
  var a3 = $.when(q3, a1).then(function (resp3) {
    console.log(resp3);
  });

  return $.when(a1, a2, a3); // Запрос считать успешным когда все действия завершились
}).then(function (...) {
  // А этот блок выполнится уже после всех действий...
});
```

Раз в вашем вопросе речь шла о массиве - наверное, у вас будет все не так просто (ну или не так сложно, тут как посмотреть). Упорядоченный список примитивов работы с ajax-запросами и обещаниями вы можете посмотреть в моем старом ответе:

[Последовательное выполнение JSONP](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/470474/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-jsonp/470649#470649)

Что-то конкретное подсказать не могу, поскольку вопрос слишком общий.

Answer (score 0):

```
function iterate(arr) {
    return arr.reduce((el,promise) => {
        return promise.then(result => {
            if(!result) {
                return el
            } else if(result instanceOf Array) {
                return iterate(result)
            } else {
                return result
            }
        })
    }, Promise.resolve())
}

iterate([$.post('/some-url')]).then(() => {
    //code after all requests
})
```

Answer (score -2):

Если правильно понял логику, попробуйте создавать переменные и присваивать им значение и проверять чему они равны.

Comment: не правильно понял)

Comment: @neek а если проверка будет до того как проставилось значение из предыдущего ajax-запроса?

Comment: @alias ...и что?

Comment: @PavelMayorov следующих запросов не будет. В момент проверки предыдущий запрос еще не будет выполнен соответственно переменная, которая для проверки не будет изменена.