# Асинхронные функции nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

Использую вызов асинхронных функций внутри асинхронных функций.
Необходимо записывать результат работы всех функций в callback асинхронной функции, в которой вызываются остальные.

Не могу понять куда приткнуть этот callback. В варианте, который в коде, в callback передаются данные после каждого их добавления, а требуется передать сразу все данные.

Если ставить callback в другой строке, то он "вылетает" из выполнения асинхронных функций и выполняется раньше, чем придут данные (что ожидаемо).

Как правильно обернуть функцию, чтобы callback не формировался (если это верный термин), пока не будут записаны все данные?

```js
sendStudentTable: function (discipline, faculty, course, firstDate, lastDate, callback) {
        var dataval = [];
        var student = require('./createStudent');
        this.findAll().then(function (data) {
            if (!data) {
                callback(null, "Таблица пустая");
            } else {

                 data.forEach(function (item, i, data) {

                    student.getDiscipline(data[i].dataValues.uniqID, function (disc, err) {

                        if (err){
                            callback(null, "ошибка в поиске дисциплины");
                        } else {

                            if (discipline == disc) {

                                student.getSource(data[i].dataValues.uniqID, function (source, err) {

                                    if (err){
                                         callback (null, "ошибка в чём-то");
                                    } else {

                                        if (source.faculty == faculty && source.course == course) {
                                             dataval.push(data[i].dataValues.name);
                                             callback(dataval, null);
                                        }
                                    }
                                })
                            }
                        }
                    });
                 });
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: @Doofy подправил по отступам в вебшторме. Не знаю стало ли особо читабельнее.

Comment: Поправил вопрос. Если всё верно, внесите правку

Comment: @Doofy посмотрел вашу правку, внёс изменения. Спасибо за помощь в оформлении.
Ещё было бы интересно понять как правильно обернуть callback:)

Comment: Используйте Promise

Answer (score 2):

Почему у вас `this.findAll` возвращает обещание (Promise), а `student.getDiscipline` требует callback? Я бы рекомендовал вам привести ваш код к одному знаменателю. И лучше бы это были обещания, а не колбэки.

Причина предпочтительности обещаний - их можно комбинировать, и они защищены от повторного вызова.

Вот мой старый ответ, где расписано про комбинирование обещаний: [Последовательное выполнение JSONP](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/470474/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-jsonp/470649#470649). Там комбинирование обещаний рассматривается для ajax-запросов - но заменить их на любой другой тип запросов не трудно.

Единственное значимое отличие - вместо `$.when(...)` надо использовать `Promise.all([...])` (внимание на литерал массива), а вместо `$.when.apply($, ...)` можно написать просто `Promise.all(...)`.

Comment: Здесь `findAll()` это функция `sequelize`, которая работает с Promises. Все функции у меня написаны на коллбэках, получается, что все надо переписывать на обещания.

Answer (score 2):

В данном случае нужно дождаться, пока завершаться все асинхронные функции, запущенные в цикле. После завершения всех функций dataval будет содержать все значения, т.к. определен глобально относительно getDiscipline. Можно подсчитать, сколько функций было выполнено, основываясь на количестве значений в data.

```
// определить где-то снаружи getDiscipline
var totalFuncs = data.length;
var doneFuncs = 0;

// это завершающий код, после выполнения условий
doneFuncs += 1;

// эта функция последняя
if(doneFuncs == totalFunc) {
  callback(dataval); 
}
```

Замечания:

- Для управления потоком асинхронных операций удобно использовать специально предназначенные библиотеки вроде [async](https://github.com/caolan/async)
- Для работы со значениями, которые будут доступны в будущем можно использовать Promise, тогда чтобы собрать все значения можно использовать Promise.all([..]).then(..)
- У вас не соблюдается соглашение об использовании callback функций, обычно используется форма callback(err, value)

Comment: Считать функции основываясь на количестве значений не выйдет, потому что `doneFuncs` заполнится ещё до получения данных. И когда первый раз попадём в финальное условие, то `doneFuncs == totalFuncs`. Пытался делать async, тоже не вышло, видимо, не до конца разобрался в нём.

Comment: Почему заполниться до получения? В том и смысл, что увеличивать его надо после получения, в этом месте:

if (source.faculty == faculty && source.course == course) {
   // тут
  dataval.push(data[i].dataValues.name);
  doneFuncs += 1;

}

Comment: Так ведь не все записи из `data` соответствуют этому условию. В `data`, допустим, 5 записей, а соответствуют 3. Значит `doneFunc` никогда не будет 5

Comment: А, ну да. Тогда не проще ли data отфильтровать используя Array.filter по этому условию

var r = data.filter(... твой код, где заменить финальный if на return - условие) -> останутся только значения подходящие под условие

Comment: Интересный вариант, но как тогда передать `r` в коллбэк после фильтрации?

Comment: Я написал длинный комментарий с советами по рефакторингу, а потом понял, что doneFunc нужно увеличивать после получения данных, но _вне условия_. Например, последней строчкой в последнем else { ... doneFunc += 1; }. Т.е. мы считаем завершение всех функций вне зависимости от условия.

Comment: Не выйдет так. Если ставить после последнего, то считает только для тех, у кого дисциплина равна, если ставить за пределами этого условия, то `donFunc` сразу же заполнится. Таким способом тут не сделать.