# Как выполнить последовательно несколько асинхронных фунций в Javascript без коллбэков?

Tags: javascript, jquery, асинхронность, promise

Как написать простой, понятный, легко обслуживаемый код, который запускает последовательно несколько асинхронных функций в javascript/jQuery?
(когда отработает одна, должна запускаться другая)

Следующий пример иллюстриует мой вопрос:

```
function f1(){ setTimeout( function(){ console.log(1); }, 30); }
function f2(){ setTimeout( function(){ console.log(2); }, 20); }
function f3(){ setTimeout( function(){ console.log(3); }, 10); }
f1(); f2(); f3();
```

на выходе 3 2 1
как сделать что-бы выдавало 1 2 3  ?

Желательно без коллбеков - т.к. если надо запустить последовательно больше двух функций это уже тяжело читать.
Многое говорит о том что возможно решение с помощью обьекта $.Deferred, но пока не видел разумного варианта.

Подобный вопрос задавался не раз, но я почему-то не нашел ответа который бы меня устроил.

Comment: Напишите функцию setSyncTimeout, которая будет циклить проверку времени запуска функции и текущее время. А в вашем примере время запуска setTimeout должно быть 30, 20+30, 20+30+10

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/470474/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-jsonp/470649#470649

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky ставлю галку, но она почемуто опять пропадает и второй раз ее поставить сразу не удается...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Если вы хотите использовать *Обещания* (Promise), то для начала вам нужно модифицировать ваши функции так, чтобы они возвращали *Обещания*. Например, первая из ваших функций будет иметь вид:

```
function f1() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve){
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log(1);
            resolve();
        }, 30);
    });
}
```

<sub>Остальные функции преобразуются аналогичным образом.</sub>

Теперь у вас есть три функции (`f1`, `f2`, `f3`), которые возвращают *Обещания* и вы хотите выполнить их последовательно. Если вы не используете библиотек, вроде Bluebird, то вам придется реализовать очередь вызова *Обещаний* вручную. Это не так сложно, как кажется:

```
// Аргумент "deeds" - это массив функций, которые должны выполняться
// последовательно. При этом, каждая функция должна возвращать
// Обещание (Promise).
var seqRunner = function(deeds) {
    return deeds.reduce(function(p, deed) {
        return p.then(function() {
            // Выполняем следующую функцию только после того, как отработала
            // предыдущая.
            return deed();
        });
    }, Promise.resolve()); // Инициализируем очередь выполнения.
}
```

А пользоваться этой очередью нужно вот так:

```
seqRunner([f1, f2, f3]).then(function() {
    console.log('Done!');
});
```

А вот и JSFiddle с [рабочим примером](https://jsfiddle.net/we0y2hg2/1/).

---

**Замечание:**

Если у вас заранее известное, небольшое число функций, то можно вообще обойтись без функции `seqRunner` и связывать функции вручную:

```
f1().then(function() {
    return f2();
}).then(function() {
    return f3();
}).then(function() {
    console.log('Done!');
});
```

Comment: если не ошибаюсь можно анонимные функции не накручивать и обойтись прямой передачей: `f1().then(f2).then(f3).then(...)`

Comment: Можно. Но тут все зависит от аргументов, принимаемых (и возвращаемых через Обещания) функциями `f1`, `f2`, `f3`. В данном конкретном случае, обертки действительно не нужны.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev Спасибо! это решение которое я хотел узнать :)
подскажете: каким фреймворком вы бы воспользовались чтобы это реализовать еще проще? (все-таки выглядит немного сложновато...)
кстати, вы упомянули библиотеку Bluebird - с ее помощью можно тоже?

Comment: @Serafim, насколько мне помнится, в bluebird такого функционала нет. А насчет громоздкости, то при желании код можно сократить. Собственно я не считаю, что для этого нужно подтягивать какой-то тяжелый фреймворк. При желании, можно подтянуть маленькую библиотечку из npm реализующую только аналог функции `seqRunner` из ответа. Конкретной библиотеки не подскажу т.к. не использую.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev если позволите я уточню некоторые моменты в которых я не совсем уверен: 1. Promise это Deferred без методов resolve и reject, которые в данном случае не нужны т.к. запускаются один раз при создании обьекта. 2. Функция которой инициализируется Promise запускается при создании Promise а параметр resolve - это метод объекта  Deferred ,  который запускает все коллбеки в случае успеха. 3.  метод , then() делает то же что и done() - т.е. навешивается коллбеки а используете вы его на случай, если вдруг понадобится навесить обработчики ошибок...

Comment: @Serafim, если честно, я бы вообще выкинул Deferred на помойку по одной простой причине: Promise (по Стандарту A+ Promise) приняли как часть стандарта ES6. Основные браузеры уже реализуют Promise без всяких сторонних библиотек, а в тех, что не реализуют - можно использовать полифилы. Теперь  о ваших вопросах: 1. да 2. да 3. `then` можно использовать аналогично `deferred.then` (два аргумента). без второго аргумента `promise.then = deferred.done`. ну и `promise.catch = deferred.fail`. Возможно тут есть особенности с потоком выполнения, но сходу не скажу

Answer (score 4):

Альтернативный вариант, сделать обертку над `setTimeout` возвращающую [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), например так:

```
function delay(timeout){
    return new Promise(function(r){
        setTimeout(r,timeout);
    });
}
```

Теперь код из вопроса может выглядеть следующим образом:

```js
function delay(timeout) {
  return new Promise(function(r) {
    setTimeout(r, timeout);
  });
}

function f1() {
  console.log(1);
}

function f2() {
  console.log(2);
}

function f3() {
  console.log(3);
}
delay(3000).then(f1)
  .then(function(){return delay(2000);})
  .then(f2)
  .then(function(){ return delay(1000);})
  .then(f3)
  .then(function() {
    console.log('all finish');
  });
```

Или даже так

```js
function delay(timeout) {
  return new Promise(function(r) {
    setTimeout(r, timeout);
  });
}

function f1() {
  console.log(1);
  return 2000
}

function f2() {
  console.log(2);
  return 1000;
}

function f3() {
  console.log(3);
}
delay(3000).then(f1)
  .then(delay)
  .then(f2)
  .then(delay)
  .then(f3)
  .then(function() {
    console.log('all finish');
  });
```

Если таких функций много, то можно собрать из них массив и с помощью функции [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) собрать один большой Promise

```js
function delay(timeout) {
  return new Promise(function(r) {
    setTimeout(r, timeout);
  });
}

function f1() {
  console.log(1);
  return 2000
}

function f2() {
  console.log(2);
  return 1000;
}

function f3() {
  console.log(3);
}

[f1, f2, f3].reduce(function(promise, func) {
    return promise.then(func).then(delay);
  }, delay(3000))
  .then(function() {
    console.log('all finish')
  });
```

Comment: Что-то мне подсказывает, что таймеры - только пример

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, не исключено, но в принципе функция delay, просто заменяется на любую другую функцию возвращающую promise, а сам подход остается тем же

Comment: Тогда в чем принципиальное отличие вашего ответа от моего? =)

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, тем, что у меня функции `f` - сами по себе не асинхронные :)

Answer (score 2):

Если каждой добавить таки callback отчёт о выполнении, можно держать очередь в массиве и вызывать следующую ф-ю по завершению предыдущей:

```
function f1(){ setTimeout( function(){ console.log(1); next(); }, 30); }
function f2(){ setTimeout( function(){ console.log(2); next(); }, 20); }
function f3(){ setTimeout( function(){ console.log(3); next(); }, 10); }

var queue = [f1, f2, f3]
    ,i=0
    ,next = function(){ queue[i]  &&  queue[i++]();}
;

next(); // 1 2 3
```

Comment: может вместо счетчика массив как очередь использовать? я имею ввиду `pop` вернее `shift`

Comment: @Grundy как вариант – но вдруг там захочется вернуться на пару шагов назад, если что-то пошло не так : )

Comment: Это тогда будет какая-то супер очередь :-)

Comment: queue[i]  &&  queue[i++]();

Comment: @Serafim вам не понятен этот фрагмент кода? Он проверяет, существует ли элемент массива `queue[i]`, содержащий ф-ю, и если да, то выполняет эту функцию, и затем увеличивает `i` на 1.

Comment: это 80-й уровень сложности. 
Уровень бога: if( queue[i] ){ queue[i](); i++; }  Но это дело вкуса :)

Comment: спасибо мне очень понравился вашь вариант! выглядит просто и понятно.

Comment: уровень макаронного монстра: `if(i<queue.length){ queue[i](); i = i + 1; }` : )

Comment: @Sergiks да! это еще лучше!

Answer (score 1):

`async function go(){
            await f1();
            await f2();
            await f3();
        }
go();`