# Последовательный вызов асинхронных функций через promise

Tags: javascript, promise

Есть такой код, который взят [отсюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/536917/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B2-javascript-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB):

```js
var f1 = function() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(1);
      resolve();
    }, 1000);
  });
}

var f2 = function() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(2);
      resolve();
    }, 2000);
  });
}

var f3 = function() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(3);
      resolve();
    }, 3000);
  });
}

var seqRunner = function(deeds) {
  return deeds.reduce(function(p, deed) {
    return p.then(deed);
  }, Promise.resolve());
}

seqRunner([f1, f2, f3]).then(function() {
  console.log('Done!');
});;
```

Объясните мне, пожалуйста, я совсем не понимаю: зачем и с какой целью функция `seqRunner` должна возвращать пустой промис?
Понятно, что после выполнения всех очередей `deeds`, она вызывает `Promise.resolve()`, чтобы выполнился внешний `.then` с командой вывода на консоль `Done!`. Это понятно. Но я думал, что если уберу в конце

```
.then(function() {
   console.log('Done!');
});;
```

А также `, Promise.resolve())`, то очередь также будет работать без ошибок.
Видит бог, не понимаю я промисы. Зачем этот `, Promise.resolve())` в возвращении функции `seqRunner`?
Почему нельзя сделать так:

```
var seqRunner = function(deeds) {
  return deeds.reduce(function(p, deed) {
    return p.then(deed);
  };
}

seqRunner([f1, f2, f3]);
```

Comment: _Promise.resolve()_ - это отправная точка, для сборки массива обещаний. В общем случае как ты предлагаешь сделать нельзя, потому что, в массиве хранятся promise, а первый параметр в then должен быть функцией. Хотя нет, в данном случае в массиве функции, но в этом случае - у функций нет метода _then_

Comment: @Grundy, не, не так. Первый параметр должен быть промисом, а не функцией.   Я [понял](http://joxi.ru/krDk8WLsELp0GA), но из-за своей невнимательности встал в ступор. Инструкция `, Promise.resolve());` находится не в `return` функции `seqRunner`, а передается как второй параметр для `reduce`.  А второй параметр для неё, это начальное значение для предыдущего (первого параметра, `p`) параметра. Таким образом, получается [такая цепочка](http://joxi.ru/eAO6lxLhxEMxe2). Первый промис сразу же решенный получается, для того, чтобы следующий мог быть уже "навешанным" на него... Так ли я всё понял?

Comment: :-D теперь я не понял

Comment: Кстати, в том ответе, на который вы ссылаетесь есть недвусмысленный комментарий "_Инициализируем очередь выполнения_" как раз рядом с `Promise.resolve()`.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, все эти комментарии идут прахом, когда ты просто не заметил скобочку и думаешь, что `Promise.resolve()` относится уже к другому (:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы зря считаете, что второй аргумент функции reduce - это последнее обещание (promise) в цепочке. Если [посмотреть что эта функция делает](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) - то будет видно, что это **первое** обещание, начальное значение!

Конструкция `[f1, f2, f3].reduce((p, deed) => p.then(deed), Promise.resolve())` в процессе выполнения раскрываете вот в такую:

```
Promise.resolve().then(f1).then(f2).then(f3)
```

Убрать отсюда начальное значение не-так-то и просто. Если вы будете писать цепочку вызовов руками, вы, наверное, напишите вот так:

```
f1().then(f2).then(f3)
```

Обратите внимание: последовательность теперь обрабатывается неоднородно. Чтобы достичь такого же эффекта через reduce над массивом - надо сначала отрезать у нее первый элемент и обработать его отдельно:

```
var seqRunner = function(deeds) {
  var first = deeds.shift();
  return deeds.reduce(function(p, deed) {
    return p.then(deed);
  }, first());
}
```

Как видно, код проще не стал, скорее даже усложнился. Причем он от этого стал намного *хуже* - в нем появились баги:

1. если вызов `f1()` выкинет исключение - то старый код ловил его и сохранял в промиз, так же как для любого другого метода. Новый код исключение из f1 выкинет дальше по стеку вызовов;
2. измененный код меняет переданный ему массив. Для вызовов вида `seqRunner([f1, f2, f3])` это не проблема - а вот если вызывать его над хранимым массивом, будет сюрприз. Работа без изменения массива будет еще сложнее;
3. старый код возвращал `Promise.resolve()` при вызове на пустом массиве, новый же требует хотя бы 1 элемента.

PS вот корректный код без этих багов в свежем синтаксисе:

```
var seqRunner = function([first, ...tail]) {
  if (first === undefined) return Promise.resolve();
  try {
    return tail.reduce((p, deed) => p.then(deed), first());
  } catch (e) {
    return Promise.reject(e);
  }
}
```

Как видно, начинать через `Promise.resolve()` - намного проще.

---

Выбор "пустого" начального значения при обходе массива с накоплением результата является общим правилом. Так, при суммировании членов массива накапливать сумму начинают с 0, при поиске минимального числа в массиве начинают с бесконечности, ну а последовательное выполнение асинхронных методов начинают с `Promise.resolve()`. Потому что так проще и красивее.

Comment: Только что об этом написал в комментарии под вопросом (: Разобрался с этим. Я вообще думал, что это возвращение функции `seqRunner ` так-то, а не второй параметр `reduce`, поэтому и задал вопрос. Но это просто невнимательность.

Comment: с третьим пунктом не согласен: shift На пустом массиве - вернет undefine, который передастся в качестве аккумулятора, и ошибки не будет - просто вернется пустой массив. А, стоп, да, ты прав, при вызове функции все упадет. Печально.

Answer (score 2):

Все ваши умозаключения строятся из неверной предпосылки:

> Понятно, что после выполнения всех очередей `deeds`, она вызывает `Promise.resolve()`, чтобы выполнился внешний `.then` с командой вывода на консоль `Done!`. Это понятно.

Это неверно.

Передавая второй аргумент методу [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), вы используете его значение как **начальное значение** аккумулятора. Вот простой пример:

```
var sum = [1, 1, 1].reduce(function (acc, val) {
    return acc + val;
}, 10);
console.log(sum); // 13
```

В вашем же случае, необходимо задать начальное значение в `Promise.resolve`, чтобы инициировать цепочку выполнения обещаний.

Конструкция:

```
seqRunner([f1, f2, f3]).then(function() {
    console.log('Done!');
});
```

эквивалентна

```
Promise.resolve()
    .then(f1)
    .then(f2)
    .then(f3)
    .then(function () {
        console.log('Done!');
    });
```

Как следствие, использование чего-либо, отличного от Обещания в начале цепочки сделает ее невалидной.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, это просто моя невнимательность (: