# Почему callback выполняется раньше чем тело вызывающей его функции?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, callback

Доброго времени суток. Постараюсь вкратце объянить свою проблему. Пишу свое первое приложение на angularJS, поэтому сильно не удивляйтесь если найдете в коде что то очень странное.

Приложение работает с api instagram и делает 2 запроса к api, разница в запрашиваемых хештегах. После получения ответа от api нужные объекты кладутся в соответствующие массивы.

```
function getResponseApi(tag, storage) {
  $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/' + tag + '/media/recent',
    params: {access_token: CLIENT_ID}
  }).then(function successCallback(response) {
    console.log(response);

    storage === 'left' ? $scope.dataStorage1 = response.data.data 
      : $scope.dataStorage2 = response.data.data;
  });
}
```

Далее приложение сравнивает оба массива и кладет совпадающие результаты в третий массив из которого они выводятся в представление.

```
function getCommonData() {
  let i, j;

  for(i in $scope.dataStorage1) {
    for (j in $scope.dataStorage2) {
      if ($scope.dataStorage1[i].caption.id === $scope.dataStorage2[j].caption.id ) {
        if (!$scope.commonDataStorage.includes($scope.dataStorage1[i])) {
          $scope.commonDataStorage.unshift($scope.dataStorage1[i]);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

При запуске приложения выполняется функция вызывающая 2 запроса к api и функцию вывода результата, естественно вывод результата выполняется раньше чем будет получен ответы от сервера, поэтому пытаюсь вызвать функцию вывода результата через callback,

```
$scope.appStart = function(callback) {
  getResponseApi($scope.tag1, 'left');
  getResponseApi($scope.tag2, 'right');
  callback();
};

$scope.appStart(getCommonData);
```

но все равно получаю то же самое, функция выполняется раньше чем приходит ответ от сервера. Подскажите пожалуйста, что делаю не так?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/536917/186083

Comment: @Visman Спасибо за отклик! Изменил функции так чтобы они возвращали промис, и сделал вызом по цепочке через then, и все равно функция вывода результата выполняется первой. Может подскажите как быть конкретно в моем случае?