# выполнить одну функцию после завершения другой

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise

Как добиться выполнения данного кода последовательно? Я попробовала несколько вариантов, ничего не работает, неизменно в консоль сначала выводится 'second', потом 'first'

```
const command = async () => {
 setTimeout(() => console.log('first'), 800)
} 
const start = async () => {
 await command();
 console.log('second');
}
start()
```

```
const command = async () => {
  setTimeout(() => console.log('first'), 800)
 } 
 const start = async () => {
  command().then(() => {
    console.log('second');
  })
 }
 start()
```

```
const command = async () => {
  setTimeout(() => console.log('first'), 800)
 } 
 const start = async () => {
  new Promise((res, rej) => {
    command()
    res()
  }).then(() => console.log('second'))
 }
 start()
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как выполнить последовательно несколько асинхронных фунций в Javascript без коллбэков?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/536917/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%85%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b2-javascript-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bb)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Вашем случае `SetTimeout` никак не связан с завершением асинхронной функции `command`, для того чтобы сделать эту связь нужно в `return` вернуть `Promise`, который будет резолвится(`resolve()`) сразу после того как отработает `console.log`.

Сейчас вызов `command` запускает `SetTimeout`, функция таймаута `() => console.log('first')` попадает в `event loop` и происходит мгновенный выход из функции `command` (c возвратом `undefined`).

**Решение:**

Так как в 3-х случаях функция `сommand` та же, я сократил немного код и сделал ее общей для всех трех случаев, добавил индексы для того чтобы не было конфликта имен, и поправил третий случай `start`:

```js
const command = async(n) => new Promise(resolve => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('first' + n)
    resolve()
  }, 800)
})

const start1 = async() => {
 await command(1);
 console.log('second1');
}

const start2 = async() => {
  command(2).then(() => {
    console.log('second2');
  })
}

const start3 = async() => {
  new Promise(async(res, rej) => {
    await command(3) // добавлен await
    res()
  }).then(() => console.log('second3'))
}

start1()
start2()
start3()
```

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте следующий код:

```js
const command = new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        resolve(console.log("first"))
    }, 800);
});

command.then(()=>{
    console.log("second")
})
```

Или же:

```js
const command = async () => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('first');
            resolve();
        }, 800);
    });
};

const start = async () => {
    await command();
    console.log('second');
};

start();
```

`command()` возвращает новый промис, который выполняется с помощью `setTimeout()`. Когда он заканчивается, промис разрешается с помощью `resolve()`. Затем в `start()`, `await command()` ждет, пока промис не разрешится, и только тогда вызывается `console.log("second")`.